# Fill Percentage area in a custom Progress Bar SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am new to SVG and stuck with a small task.

I would like to fill a custom SVG to a specific percentage.

Here is my initial SVG

```html
<svg width="233" height="9" viewBox="0 0 233 9" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path id="base1" d="M0.0104229 4.53685C0.585564 0.0541843 77.5774 0.498692 134.721 1.59593C171.989 2.31113 232.913 -0.235688 232.75 4.22739C232.525 10.3451 134.045 7.87626 89.0013 7.23356C39.1891 6.52242 -0.727053 10.2816 0.0104229 4.53685Z" fill="#DADBDD"></path></svg>
```

Here is my final SVG

```html
            <svg width="233" height="9" viewBox="0 0 233 9" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M0.0104229 4.53685C0.585564 0.0541843 77.5774 0.498692 134.721 1.59593C171.989 2.31113 232.913 -0.235688 232.75 4.22739C232.525 10.3451 134.045 7.87626 89.0013 7.23356C39.1891 6.52242 -0.727053 10.2816 0.0104229 4.53685Z" fill="#DADBDD" />
              <mask id="mask0" mask-type="alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="233" height="9">
                <path d="M0.0104229 4.53685C0.585564 0.0541843 77.5774 0.498692 134.721 1.59593C171.989 2.31113 232.913 -0.235688 232.75 4.22739C232.525 10.3451 134.045 7.87626 89.0013 7.23356C39.1891 6.52242 -0.727053 10.2816 0.0104229 4.53685Z" fill="#DADBDD" />
              </mask>
              <g mask="url(#mask0)">
                <ellipse rx="49.9644" ry="25.4799" transform="matrix(0.943377 0.331722 -0.657906 0.7531 34.4845 13.7852)" fill="#ED718F" />
              </g>
            </svg>
```

I want to fill this with the percentage area as entered by the user.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to write any javascript yourself to accomplish this task? If so, show us where you got stuck. If not, give it a try and report back.

Comment: I don't understand why are you using an ellipse to fill the shape. If a mask is in your mind you can use a thick line (stroke-width="9" - for example) instead of the ellipse, and you can mask this line. Then you can change the stroke-dasharray as in the other question

Comment: @enxaneta - Thanks for the guidance. Actually, I am completely naive to SVG. I don't have any prior knowledge to it.

I also tried using <use> as explained by you in the previous question but I was unable to achieve the result.

it would be great if you can post a solution to show how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've commented: if you want to use a maska mask you can use a thick line (stroke-width="9" - for example) instead of the ellipse, and you can mask this line. Then you can change the stroke-dasharray according to the percentage you have.

```js
//the total length of the line which in this case is as long as the shape
let tl = theLine.getTotalLength();
// the percentage for the progress
let xperc = itr.value;

onInput();

itr.addEventListener("input", onInput);

// a function that is setting the value for the stroke-dasharray of the line according with the progress
function onInput() {
  xperc = itr.value;
  theLine.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", `${tl * xperc} ${tl - tl * xperc}`);
}
```

```html
<input id="itr" type="range" min="0" max="1" value="0.35" step=".001" /><br>

<svg width="233" height="9" viewBox="0 0 233 9" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <defs>
     <path id="theShape" d="M0.0104229 4.53685C0.585564 0.0541843 77.5774 0.498692 134.721 1.59593C171.989 2.31113 232.913 -0.235688 232.75 4.22739C232.525 10.3451 134.045 7.87626 89.0013 7.23356C39.1891 6.52242 -0.727053 10.2816 0.0104229 4.53685Z" />

     <mask id="mask0" mask-type="alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="233" height="9">
       <use xlink:href="#theShape" fill="#fff" />
     </mask>
   </defs>
   
   <use xlink:href="#theShape" fill="#DADBDD" />
   
   <path id="theLine" d="M0 4.5L233 4.5" stroke="#ED718F" stroke-width="9" mask="url(#mask0)" />

 </svg>
```